# Will S be an empty set if the least upper bound is equal to the greatest lower bound?

Tags: analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Will S be an empty set if the least upper bound is equal to the greatest lower bound?

Also will S be an empty set if the maximum is equal to the minimum?

Comment: Consider a point in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Will it be an empty set? Yes or No?

Comment: To be a little more explicit, if $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and $S=\{x\}$, then $\mathrm{lub\ } S=\mathrm{glb\ } S=x$.

Comment: @ForgotALot   So when there is only one element in the set, LUB is equal to GLB? Got it! Thank you so much

Comment: If $S$ is the empty set, the least upper bound and the greatest lower bound are **not** equal, they are as far apart as possible.

Comment: @bof  How are they far apart when S is empty??? (- ∞ ,+ ∞) is obviously not an empty set! Can you explain a lil bit more?

Comment: The empty set has a sup of $-\infty$ and an inf of $+\infty$.

Comment: @ZacharySelk Got it Zach!    Can you answer my second question: What are the maximum and minimum like for an empty set?

Comment: It has no maximum or minimum.

Comment: @ZacharySelk THANKS!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

No.

In the reals empty sets don't have sups or infs or max or mins. In the extended reals $\sup \emptyset = -\infty \ne \infty = \inf \emptyset$.  So this is *not* a property of empty sets.

So if $\sup A = \inf A$ then $A \ne \emptyset$.  The *real* question is, does there exist any set such that $\sup A = \inf A$ or is that an impossibility?

If a set $A$  has $\max A = \min A$ then $\max A \in A$ and $\min A \in A$ and for any $x \in A$,  $x \ge \min A = \max A$ and $x \le \min A= \max A$ so by exclusion principal of order $x = \min A = \max A$ so $A$ has exactly one element.

If a set $A$ is such that $\inf A = \sup A$ then means for any $y < \inf A$ there exists an $x_0\in A$ so that $y < x_0 \le \inf A=\sup A$.  And for any $w > \sup A $ then there exists a $x_1\in$ so that $\inf A = \sup A \le x_1 < w$.

But if $x_0 < \inf A$ it is not in $A$.  So $x_0 = \inf A$.  And if $x_1 > \sup A$ is is not in $A$.  So $x_1 = \sup A$.

So $A$ will contain only one element.

The only sets with this propertys are the sets with one elements $A = \{x\}$ and $x = \inf A = \sup A = \min A = \max A$.

Comment: "Empty sets don't have sups or infs" in many texts they're defined to be $-\infty$ and $+\infty$

Comment: Aren't such texts a minority? and doesn't that require more definitions and conditions as that makes all sets bounded? and empty sets infinite?  And what about the condition that for all $w > \inf \emptyset = - \infty$ there is a $x \in \emptyset $ so that $ x \ge w$.  seems more trouble then it's worth.   Meanwhile is $-\infty = \infty$?  If not then $\inf \emptyset \ne \sup \emptyset$.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I see.  Any element is greater then every element of the empty set so is an upper bound.  And if are in the extended number line all sets are bounded.  Okay but in the reals there are none.

Comment: It's very common. And it's just a convention, it doesn't make all sets bounded. And you got it mixed up. $\inf \emptyset=+\infty$

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: But it is only for the extended reals.

Comment: Oh, $\sup  \emptyset = -\infty$ because all num are lower bounds so the least of them is $-\infty$.  Yes, that makes sense.  And indeed for all $w < -\infty$ there is an $x \in \emptyset$ so that $w \le x \le -\infty$.  That makes perfect sense in the vaccuuous way.  I withdraw my objections.

Comment: And like a novice, I let the vacuuity of $\sup A < \inf A$ cloud my judgement.  Obviously that's impossible if there are elements but it would *have* to follow if there were *no* elements  Okay, I'm liking this.

Comment: Well all numbers are *upper* bounds so the least of them is $-\infty$, but yes that's the right idea!

Comment: Oops.  That was a typo.  I meant to type exactly what you wrote.